# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '']?)(" ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried to fix an error in Wordpress backend for WPML plugin with this suggestion: https://wpml.org/errata/product-variations-not-display-variation-original-language/

It didn't work and now I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '']?)(" '
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in
>   /home/sweetcelebration.nl/public_html/sweetcelebration.nl/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 527

I pasted the code in the beginning of functions.php and removed it when it didn't work. I didn't touch this part of the code, so I'm not sure why this now appears.

```
function wp_extract_urls( $content ) {
    preg_match_all(
        "#(["']?)("
            . "(?:([w-]+:)?//?)"
            . "[^s()<>]+"
            . "[.]"
            . "(?:"
                . "([wd]+)|"
                . "(?:"
                    . "[^`!()[]{};:'".,<>«»“”‘’s]|"
                    . "(?:[:]d+)?/?"
                . ")+"
            . ")"
        . ")1#",
        $content,
        $post_links
    );

    $post_links = array_unique( array_map( 'html_entity_decode', $post_links[2] ) );
    return array_values( $post_links );
}
```

Line 527 is

> . "[^`!()[]{};:'".,<>«»“”‘’s]|"

I'm sorry if this is stupid question. I did read other similar questions that were asked before, but didn't find my answer. I'm really hoping someone here can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to escape the quote character inside the regex. It is parsed as string literal ending.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape all `"` characters (being part of the regex itself) with a backslash:

`"#(["']?)("`

becomes

`"#([\"']?)("`

And:

```
. "[^`!()[]{};:'".,<>«»“”‘’s]|"
```

becomes:

```
. "[^`!()[]{};:'\".,<>«»“”‘’s]|"
```

This should solve it:

```
preg_match_all(
    "#([\"']?)("
        . "(?:([w-]+:)?//?)"
        . "[^s()<>]+"
        . "[.]"
        . "(?:"
            . "([wd]+)|"
            . "(?:"
                . "[^`!()[]{};:'\".,<>«»“”‘’s]|"
                . "(?:[:]d+)?/?"
            . ")+"
        . ")"
    . ")1#",
    $content,
    $post_links
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The interstitial " marks in that line need to be escaped. E.g.:

```
. "[^`!()[]{};:'\".,<>«»“”‘’s]|"
```